# Automatic comments in the first post review queue

Tags: feature-request, review

**The question:**

Can an automatic comment system be implemented in the first post review queue?

**Motivation:**

I'd like to have an option for adding automatic comments in first post review queue, just like there are options for automatic comments in the low quality review. These comments should probably be site-specific and be editable by moderators. (and maybe be suggested by 1K+ users)

For example:
On Math.SE, new users often don't add their attempt to the question, but that is required. So I'd like to be able to add an automatic comment saying something like:

> Welcome to Math.SE. On this site, it is required to add your attempt
>   to the question. This is so that users can point out your mistake,
>   give you an appropriate hint or give you an answer in the direction
>   you are seeking it.

Likewise, I'd like to be able to add a comment to explain they should use LaTeX in their posts.

It is irritating to type this comment every time I do one or two first post reviews, and for that reason I almost never review these. However just silently flagging or voting to close won't help the OP. So that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Other than AutoReviewComments as answered, I **strongly** oppose this idea. Why? New reviewers with 500 rep that throw auto-comments at every post that looks at them funny. It would get pretty bad.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The  AutoReviewComments work okay for me, but one may enable that for 2K+, i.e. when the other queues where auto comments are available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving Community user and "share feedback" issues in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369344/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369325/282094 - the other suggested *duplicate* has 127 answers and is past the date for additional feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a userscript for this: [**AutoReviewComments**](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

The userscript adds an 'auto' button beside the comment field on posts, including but not limited to review queues, which allows you to select a comment to be added automatically to the post.

There are numerous standard comments but you can customise it with your own or add a remote JSON file which can be developed on a community's meta site.