# Why was an 'action taken' (aka the "I'm done" option) removed as a review-closing action?

Tags: support, review

> [image]
> Example: I still had to choose a canned comment

Why (as in rationale, and not a feature request) was an action taken (e.g. voting, commenting, and/or raising a flag) removed as a review-closing action?

I searched for "action taken" (the <kbd>I'm done</kbd> button) in the [list of to-do's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/392799) for the new review queue, e.g. this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/392799) is about the limited variety in canned responses, and not the action taken.

I'm just curious about the reasoning behind this particular change. Perhaps there was a downside to it that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Is (was) "Action taken" unique to aviation as the sites I curate on used "I'm done"" Now it's leave canned comment or Skip are the only ways. I think there's a [pending feature addition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/259608) when they have time, something will turn up to fill the need. How it got left-out in the first place - an oversight perhaps by people not accustomed to reviewing, or maybe there's something else in the offing not yet know.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: Indeed it was called "I'm done". I have updated the post to also inc. the answer you linked. Thanks.

Comment: This leads to all sorts of mini-puzzles where you've got a bad answer and you either have to mark it as "Looks good!" (when it's not), or edit it (when it doesn't need an edit or couldn't be salvaged by one). +1

Comment: [likely related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369209/786798) report on the announcement - not sure which review this is, so sorry if I missed the mark, stopped reviewing when the feature was rolled out in its initial state.

Comment: @OlegValter: Certainly related. While it's about *Late answers,* and the one I posted about is the new *First answers,* it seems that option was gutted there too. Which makes me even more curious. Thanks for finding that one.

Comment: @ymb1 NP! Also thanks for clarifying, it's hard to keep track which one's which now (although it is likely they all share the same cause in your case). I think I've seen a staff response that this is considered a bug, but cannot substantiate the claim now :( We barely keep the list of all reported bugs/feature requests up to date given how many there are...

Comment: I think the answer would be that the change isn't final, it's the current state after initial release while the dialogue options are still being considered. That's what to me this post reads like [Resolving Community user and "share feedback" issues in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272)

Comment: @bad_coder: Thanks for this find! It addresses one part indeed, but nothing on voting and flagging, which are more appropriate for NAAs for instance.

Comment: I'd like to see the ["working code" mentioned](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47258/what-is-this-cutout-in-the-spitfire-cockpit-glass/89082#comment239817_89082) in the review autocomment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm done button is added back now.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm too [for the *First answers*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvpeq.png) review! Yay.

Comment: Related bug report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369545/349058