# When two users select to add the same comment from different reviews, automatically upvote the original instead of posting a new one

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, late-answers

As you can see in the image below, the post has two comments that are exactly the same, but each came from different review queues (nobody commented from the [VLQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/174236) review and Lou_is from [Late Answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/174235):

[image: A screenshot of a deleted answer. There are two comments by "nobody" and "Lou_is", both of which say "If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review"]

Having two comments with the exact same wording seems redundant. Usually, if a user goes to post a canned comment that has already been posted, it will just automatically upvote the one that was already there instead. Can this also be done cross review?

Comment: This is why I end up manually upvoting a comment, then selecting "no comment". (I also find it easier than trying to select the comment from the list that will cause an automatic upvote.)

Comment: I did [already raised this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369618/571958) on the final release post but to be honest, I kinda think it actually does make sense. Each comment has the *"From review"* link which obviously links to the different review the comment originated from which does give some extra information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving Community user and "share feedback" issues in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272/282094) and     https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363552/282094

Comment: @Rob I don't think it's a duplicate of either of those posts. I scrolled through the answers to each of them and can't find the thing being proposed here in any of them. Those were both posted months ago, so they're not being watched for answers by staff anymore; the team prefers that new ideas be posted as new questions after 2-3 weeks or so. If I missed an answer proposing the same thing here, mind linking to that answer?

Comment: @Sonic The prior comment is an exact duplicate, my comment's first link falls within the allowed timeframe to accept an answer (feedback), the second link explains the changes being made; that feedback on the first link further restricts one too.

Comment: It's been 3 months since those announcements.  I sincerely doubt that any attention is being paid to those answers anymore.  This is a perfectly sensible thing to raise in a new question.  It should not be closed as a duplicate of the announcements.