# Automatically upvote an existing review queue canned comment instead of duplicating it

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, automatic-comments

I’ve noticed that if multiple users select the same canned comment in the review queues, this results in duplicate comments. This might come across as rude and annoying to the recipient, who will get multiple notifications of the same comment in their inbox. For example: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/323669.

[image: screenshot of the above example]

<sup>*How many times should we tell this user that "this does not really answer the question"?*</sup>

My feature request is: To avoid redundant comments, if a reviewer selects the same canned comment as one previously posted, instead of duplicating it, the system should automatically upvote the prior comment to indicate the reviewer’s agreement with it.

Notes:

I tagged this post with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because it seems to be related to this 2012 [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [Prevent duplicate auto-comments from review deletion recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143669/162827). According to an answer to that post, “[Prevent duplicate auto-comments] is already implemented.”

This post has been marked as a possible duplicate of the 2021 [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) post, [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/162827). But that post says:

> Report any further issues after September 10th [2021] as new questions on Meta.

This post is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report about an issue with the review queue changes mentioned in that meta post. So I don’t think it should be closed as a duplicate.

Relevant Arqade Meta posts:

- [Please don't leave redundant comments on non-answers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7028/4797)
- [Please don't leave critique comments that repeat what's already there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7895/4797)

Comment: I think the first one came from a different queue (*First answers*) while the second came from LQ. Since the review links are different in each, the system may not detect that a duplicate comment is being posted since the text forming the comment is different.

Comment: Yea, I think this is actually a valid reason to duplicate the comments, as you'd want links to both reviews in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When two users select to add the same comment from different reviews, automatically upvote the original instead of posting a new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372434/when-two-users-select-to-add-the-same-comment-from-different-reviews-automatica)

Comment: I also [brought this up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369618/571958) back when the new review queues workflow was released

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369618/282094)

Comment: @Rob No, that post does not address my feature request and bug report.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. The duplicate and comments point out that despite both messages appearing the same they link to different Review Queues; so are different messages, each 'duplicate' of each of those gets **seperate** comment upvotes. If the messages were somehow combined one of the links would be lost  and there'd be twice as many votes on the comment, leading to confusion as to how many votes were from each queue. --- The solution would be to use a **slightly** different (visible) message for each queue, retaining the different links for each.